# How to pinch in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, touch

I'm trying to manage about multi-touch. So, I'm trying to separate the behavior of touchs. Suppose the person want to zoom their picture, they need to pinch in order to zoom it. However, two fingers which two touch points are so distance will not be allow to zoom as I shown with figure below:
[image]

How can I separate that. Is there any function to do that ?

Regards,
C.Porawat

Comment: That's *nuts*. What if I want to use two fingers? Why should your application care? Buy an iPhone and spend a few days with it; it gets this type of thing right.

Comment: The reason that I need to care is I have to manage many events from many touch. I try to separate the behavior of each touch. For example, when one finger touch down for 2 seconds, the menu will appear. Also, when 2 fingers touch down for menu. The first one will be get it. But, when 2 fingers touch down it also means they need to zoom. Thus, how can I know that person want to call menu or zoom. That why I decide to use pinch to separate call menu and zoom

Comment: @PorawatChimcherdsin awesome diagram +1 :) Two finger tap should be interpreted as two fingers down without movement for 250ms say. Two fingers drag (pinch zoom) should only start after the fingers are down & start to move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this about distinguishing one-handed vs. two-handed scaling manipulation, or about imposing certain minimum/maximum zoom factors for manipulated objects?

In the first case, this is not (reliably) possible. To my knowledge, contacts do not carry identifiable information that would allow you to tell fingers of one hand apart from fingers of the other hand. As Cody noted, it is also NOT desirable for scaling gestures.

However, I take it that what you're really trying to achieve is to prevent the user from scaling an object to extreme dimensions. As the `ManipulationDelta` event that you receive (preferable to raw touch events in your case, as you'd have to derive an incremental transform matrix/scale factor by yourself) exposes a `DeltaManipulation.Scale` property, you should be able to inspect this and the current scale factor of the manipulated object (as specified by the magnitude of a row vector of your object's transformation matrix; don't remember off the top of the head if there's a convenience function to retrieve it for you?) to impose minimum/maximum scaling factors.

It might even be possible that some manipulation processor or `UIElement` has corresponding bounds pre-built for you.